# Most reliable way for responsive screen-covering images using CSS3 media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am currently designing a landing page for a personal project and I thought about using a screen-covering image (100% width and 100% height of browser window) to round up the experience.

After the usual normalization, I've started with

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#hero {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and began with loads of media queries for both portrait and landscape orientation, you'll get the concept from this snippet:

```
...

@media only screen and (min-width: 2049px) and (max-width: 2560px) and (min-height: 1441px) and (max-height: 1600px) {
    #hero {
        background-image: url(../img/hero/landscape/cover-2560-1600.jpg); /* 8:5 */
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2049px) and (max-width: 2560px) and (min-height: 1601px) and (max-height: 2048px) {
    #hero {
        background-image: url(../img/hero/landscape/cover-2560-2048.jpg); /* 5:4; */
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2561px) and (min-height: 2049px) {
    #hero {
        background-image: url(../img/hero/cover-any-max.jpg); /* fallback for ultra high resolutions */
    }
}
```

Apart from the insane amount of work that needs to be done to create a good quality image for the most used resolutions and write media queries for each single one of them, none of those queries is able to handle uncommon browser sizes, if, for example, a user drags his window to be very wide but also very short, he gets only a white background.

I would appreciate tips regarding this issue, as most coverage of responsive images I've found online was not very helpful, as it wasn't used as extensively as I desire.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a single *large* image, much larger than any resolution you would expect a visitor to your site to be using and reduce the quality right down. This does not look great at 100% size but when scaled down onto the smaller resolutions it will begin to look good. Doing this you can then use one image for portrait and one for landscape or just use one image with the following:

```
    html, body {
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
    }
    body {
        background-image:url('../img/hero/cover-any-max.jpg');
        background-size:cover;
    }
```

Portrait and landscape media queries:

```
@media only screen and (orientation : landscape)
@media only screen and (orientation : portrait)
```

For more information on the HiDPI low quality approach check out this article - [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/#toc-tech-overview)

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be a very good solution for similar problems, but in my case, I need to serve images of different aspect ratios, which means that a high-resolution low-quality 16:9 base image would most likely not only look grainy and noisy on a high-resolution 5:4 screen, it would also look horribly distortioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the aspect-ratio queries to capture when the viewport is getting very wide but also very short:

```
@media only screen (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5) and (max-aspect-ratio: 8/4)
{
    #hero {
        background-image: url(../img/hero/landscape/cover-2560-1600.jpg); /* 8:4 ~8:5 */
    }
}

/* Your other aspect-ratio queries */


/* If browser is very wide + small */
@media only screen (min-aspect-ratio: 22/1) and (max-aspect-ratio: 22/2)
{
    /* Assign other styles to handle it */
}

/* If browser is very narrow + tall */
@media only screen (min-aspect-ratio: 1/22) and (max-aspect-ratio: 2/22)
{
    /* Assign other styles to handle it */
}
```

You obviously need to determine the the breakpoints yourself.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if you just have one image this won't seem like a great solution, but if you have several, or you accept user submitted content which you don't control, then having a server side solution (RESS) which scales or crops your images on the fly to fit your visitor's screen perfectly, is really your best bet.

You'll go nuts writing out all the possible media queries and pre scaling your images. Also,  as you mention, device aspect ratios are different or you may come across devices with an odd resolution...not to mention Retina displays etc.

If you really want a fool proof approach, go RESS. I'm aware of [Pixtulate](http://www.pixtulate.com) but I'm sure there are others.